# Ring doorbell and echo dot interaction

Tags: amazon-echo, door-sensor

I have a [Ring Video Doorbell 2](https://shop.ring.com/collections/video-doorbells/products/video-doorbell-2?variant=56549602635) and an [Amazon Echo Dot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DFKC2SO). I cannot hear the chime of the doorbell throughout my home. There is an [Alexa Ring Skill](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JTL2PYE) that seems to focus on the video. It technically does not support the Dot, but it installed fine, it just doesn't do anything since it is designed to show video. I was hoping the skill would allow the doorbell to play a notification through the Dot (and possibly allow me to talk to the person).

Is there a way to integrate the Ring and the Dot?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the major part of this is now working. My Ring 2 came bundled with an echo dot, and I receive both movement and 'ring' notifications on the Dot.

The ring shows up as a 'camera' in Alexa, and the two notifications can be controlled independently.

There is no support to 'talk' to the person at the door (or even listen to audio) when using the Dot.